# Getting Status Code: 500 errors when accessing localstack Kinesis stream with Camel

Tags: apache-camel, amazon-kinesis, quarkus, localstack

I'm receiving 500 status code errors when connecting with Camel to my `localstack` Kinesis stream. Accessing and putting msgs to the stream via awslocal works fine. So it's probably not a localstack issue.

Localstack

```
# Start localstack
DEBUG=1 SERVICES=kinesis AWS_CBOR_DISABLE=true CBOR_ENABLED=false localstack start

# Setup stream
awslocal kinesis create-stream --shard-count 4 --stream-name mystream
```

Java Config (I'm using Quarkus)

```
public void configure() {
        

        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(mystream.getAccessKeyId(), mystream.getSecretKey());
        AmazonKinesis client = AmazonKinesisClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                .withEndpointConfiguration(
                        new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(mystream.getServiceEndpoint(), mystream.getRegion()))
                .build();

        getContext().setTracing(true);

        getContext().getRegistry().bind("mystreamClient", client);

        from("aws-kinesis://mystream?amazonKinesisClient=mystreamClient&bridgeErrorHandler=true&shard-id=1").routeId("mystream1").log("Received mystream");
    }
```

Error msg:
`ERROR [org.apa.cam.pro.err.DefaultErrorHandler] (Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-kinesis://mystream) Failed delivery for (MessageId: 76F94B329B1EE4F-0000000000000002 on ExchangeId: 76F94B329B1EE4F-0000000000000002). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.AmazonKinesisException: null (Service: AmazonKinesis; Status Code: 500; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)`

Comment: Please check what is the value of `mystream.getServiceEndpoint()` - `awslocal` is just a shortcut to `aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4568` (or `localhost:4566` if you're using newer localstack version which can be accessed via single port number for all services).